# Keep top N values of each row in a dataframe within groups of column indices

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm having trouble finding an elegant solution to this problem (there might not be one).

I have the following example DataFrame:

> np.random.seed(0)
>
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10)).abs()

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558  0.977278  0.950088   
1  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079   
2  2.552990  0.653619  0.864436  0.742165  2.269755  1.454366  0.045759   
3  0.154947  0.378163  0.887786  1.980796  0.347912  0.156349  1.230291   
4  1.048553  1.420018  1.706270  1.950775  0.509652  0.438074  1.252795   
5  0.895467  0.386902  0.510805  1.180632  0.028182  0.428332  0.066517   
6  0.672460  0.359553  0.813146  1.726283  0.177426  0.401781  1.630198   
7  0.729091  0.128983  1.139401  1.234826  0.402342  0.684810  0.870797   
8  1.165150  0.900826  0.465662  1.536244  1.488252  1.895889  1.178780   
9  0.403177  1.222445  0.208275  0.976639  0.356366  0.706573  0.010500   

          7         8         9  
0  0.151357  0.103219  0.410599  
1  0.205158  0.313068  0.854096  
2  0.187184  1.532779  1.469359  
3  1.202380  0.387327  0.302303  
4  0.777490  1.613898  0.212740  
5  0.302472  0.634322  0.362741  
6  0.462782  0.907298  0.051945  
7  0.578850  0.311553  0.056165  
8  0.179925  1.070753  1.054452  
9  1.785870  0.126912  0.401989
```

I have the following zones map:

> zones = {"A": [0,1,2], "B": [3,4], "C": [5,6,7,8], "D": [9]}

The zones show me groups of columns that I should examine together and for each *row* of df[columns] DataFrame, keep the top N items (**NB**: keep the top N items across the the row, i.e. cross-sectionally - see later), set the rest to zero. For example for zone "A" with N=2, I would examine the following DataFrame:

```
          0         1         2
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
2  2.552990  0.653619  0.864436
3  0.154947  0.378163  0.887786
4  1.048553  1.420018  1.706270
5  0.895467  0.386902  0.510805
6  0.672460  0.359553  0.813146
7  0.729091  0.128983  1.139401
8  1.165150  0.900826  0.465662
9  0.403177  1.222445  0.208275
```

and because N=2 I will keep the top N items:

```
          0         1         2
0  1.764052  0.        0.978738
1  0.        1.454274  0.761038
2  2.552990  0.        0.864436
3  0.        0.378163  0.887786
4  0.        1.420018  1.706270
5  0.895467  0.        0.510805
6  0.672460  0.        0.813146
7  0.729091  0.        1.139401
8  1.165150  0.900826  0.
9  0.403177  1.222445  0.
```

The entire output with the zone map above and N=2 will look like:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  1.764052  0.        0.978738  2.240893  1.867558  0.977278  0.950088   
1  0.        1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079   
2  2.552990  0.        0.864436  0.742165  2.269755  1.454366  0.         
3  0.        0.378163  0.887786  1.980796  0.347912  0.        1.230291   
4  0.        1.420018  1.706270  1.950775  0.509652  0.        1.252795   
5  0.895467  0.        0.510805  1.180632  0.028182  0.428332  0.         
6  0.672460  0.        0.813146  1.726283  0.177426  0.        1.630198   
7  0.729091  0.        1.139401  1.234826  0.402342  0.684810  0.870797   
8  1.165150  0.900826  0.        1.536244  1.488252  1.895889  1.178780   
9  0.403177  1.222445  0.        0.976639  0.356366  0.706573  0.         

          7         8         9  
0  0.        0.        0.410599  
1  0.        0.        0.854096  
2  0.        1.532779  1.469359  
3  1.202380  0.        0.302303  
4  0.        1.613898  0.212740  
5  0.        0.634322  0.362741  
6  0.        0.907298  0.051945  
7  0.        0.        0.056165  
8  0.        0.        1.054452  
9  1.785870  0.        0.401989
```

The way I am attempting to solve this feels a bit slow. I loop over the zones, then I get a zone_df and then I loop over row, sorting each row and calling row.head(len(row) - N) to get the index and columns which need to be set to 0. I then use these values (in a dict) to set cells in zone_df to zero and then combine the zone_dfs.

Comment: Do you mind adding a `np.random.seed(0)` so we can reproduce your data?

Comment: Will add and amend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
def keeptopN_perkey(df, zones, N=2):
    a = df.values
    indx = zones.values()
    r = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
    for i in indx:
        b = a[:,i]
        L = np.maximum(len(i)-N,0)
        if L>0:
            idx = np.argpartition(b, L, axis=1)[:,:L] 
            # or np.argsort(b,axis=1)[:,:L]
            b[r, idx] = 0
        a[:,i] = b
    return df
```

The benefit is that we are writing back to the input dataframe without the need to create an output dataframe with the help of using the underlying array data.

Sample run -

```
In [303]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: N = 2
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11,99,(4,10)))
     ...: zones = {"A": [0,1,2], "B": [3,4], "C": [5, 6,7,8], "D": [9]}
     ...: 

In [304]: df
Out[304]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  55  58  75  78  78  20  94  32  47  98
1  81  23  69  76  50  98  57  92  48  36
2  88  83  20  31  91  80  90  58  75  93
3  60  40  30  30  25  50  43  76  20  68

In [305]: keeptopN_perkey(df, zones, N=2)
Out[305]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0  58  75  78  78   0  94   0  47  98
1  81   0  69  76  50  98   0  92   0  36
2  88  83   0  31  91  80  90   0   0  93
3  60  40   0  30  25  50   0  76   0  68
```

### Benchmarking

Approaches from other posts -

```
def mask_n(df, n): # @piRSquared's helper func
    v = np.zeros(df.shape, dtype=bool)
    n = min(n, v.shape[1])
    if v.shape[1] > n:
        j = np.argpartition(-df.values, n, 1)[:, :n].ravel()
        i = np.arange(v.shape[0]).repeat(n)
        v[i, j] = True
        return df.where(v, 0)
    else:
        return df

def piRSquared1(df, zones): # @piRSquared's soln1
    zinv = {v: k for k in zones for v in zones[k]}
    return df.groupby(zinv, 1).apply(mask_n, n=2)

def piRSquared2(df, zones): # @piRSquared's soln2
    zinv = {v: k for k in zones for v in zones[k]}
    return df.mask(df.groupby(zinv, 1).rank(axis=1, method='first', 
                   ascending=False) > 2, 0)

def COLDSPEED1(df, zones): # @COLDSPEED's soln
    for z in zones:                   
        df2 = df.iloc[:, zones[z]]
        df.iloc[:, zones[z]] = \
                np.where(((-df2).rank(axis=1) - 1) >= 2, 0, df2.values)
    return df

def s5s1(df, zones, N=2): # @s5s's soln
    final = []
    for zone_id, cols in zones.iteritems():
        values = {}
        d = df[cols]  # zone A
        for i, row in d.iterrows():
            if len(row) > N:
                row.sort()
                row[row.head(len(row) - N).index] = 0
            values[i] = row
        d = pd.DataFrame(values).T
        final.append(d)

    return pd.concat(final, axis=1)[df.columns]
```

Timings on a bigger dataset -

```
In [458]: # Setup
     ...: ncols = 1000
     ...: cuts = np.sort(np.random.choice(ncols, ncols//3, replace=0))
     ...: indx_split = np.split(np.arange(ncols),cuts)
     ...: zones = {i:p_i for i,p_i in enumerate(list(map(list,indx_split)))}
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11,99,(10,ncols)))
     ...: N = 2
     ...: 
     ...: df1 = df.copy()
     ...: df2 = df.copy()
     ...: df3 = df.copy()
     ...: df4 = df.copy()
     ...: df5 = df.copy()
     ...: 

In [459]: %timeit COLDSPEED1(df1, zones)
     ...: %timeit piRSquared1(df2, zones)
     ...: %timeit piRSquared2(df3, zones)
     ...: %timeit s5s1(df4, zones)
     ...: %timeit keeptopN_perkey(df5, zones)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 324 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 81.6 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.47 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.99 ms per loop
```

Comment: I added another solution, I believe it takes around 12ms.

Comment: @s5s Updated timings. Looks much slower than that at my end with bigger dataset setup.

Answer (score 4):

Given a dataframe subslice:

```
df
          0         1         2
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
2  2.552990  0.653619  0.864436
3  0.154947  0.378163  0.887786
4  1.048553  1.420018  1.706270
5  0.895467  0.386902  0.510805
6  0.672460  0.359553  0.813146
7  0.729091  0.128983  1.139401
8  1.165150  0.900826  0.465662
9  0.403177  1.222445  0.208275
```

Apply `df.rank` and set all values `>= N` to `0`:

```
v = df.values
v = df.iloc[:, zones[z]] = np.where(((-df2)\
                 .rank(axis=1) - 1) >= 2, 0, df2.values)

v
array([[ 1.764052,  0.      ,  0.978738],
       [ 0.      ,  1.454274,  0.761038],
       [ 2.55299 ,  0.      ,  0.864436],
       [ 0.      ,  0.378163,  0.887786],
       [ 0.      ,  1.420018,  1.70627 ],
       [ 0.895467,  0.      ,  0.510805],
       [ 0.67246 ,  0.      ,  0.813146],
       [ 0.729091,  0.      ,  1.139401],
       [ 1.16515 ,  0.900826,  0.      ],
       [ 0.403177,  1.222445,  0.      ]])
```

---

Generalising to your dataframe, you have:

```
for z in zones:                   
    df2 = df.iloc[:, zones[z]]
    df.iloc[:, zones[z]] = \
            np.where(((-df2).rank(axis=1) - 1) >= 2, 0, df2.values)

df

          0         1         2         3          4         5         6  \
0   1.76405         0  0.978738   2.24089    1.86756  0.977278  0.950088   
1         0   1.45427  0.761038  0.121675   0.443863  0.333674   1.49408   
2   2.55299         0  0.864436  0.742165    2.26975   1.45437         0   
3         0  0.378163  0.887786    1.9808   0.347912         0   1.23029   
4         0   1.42002   1.70627   1.95078   0.509652         0    1.2528   
5  0.895467         0  0.510805   1.18063  0.0281822  0.428332         0   
6   0.67246         0  0.813146   1.72628   0.177426         0    1.6302   
7  0.729091         0    1.1394   1.23483   0.402342   0.68481  0.870797   
8   1.16515  0.900826         0   1.53624    1.48825   1.89589   1.17878   
9  0.403177   1.22245         0  0.976639   0.356366  0.706573         0   

         7         8          9  
0        0         0   0.410599  
1        0         0   0.854096  
2        0   1.53278    1.46936  
3  1.20238         0   0.302303  
4        0    1.6139    0.21274  
5        0  0.634322   0.362741  
6        0  0.907298  0.0519454  
7        0         0  0.0561653  
8        0         0    1.05445  
9  1.78587         0   0.401989
```

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
Using `np.argpartition`

```
zinv = {v: k for k in zones for v in zones[k]}

def mask_n(df, n):
    v = np.zeros(df.shape, dtype=bool)
    n = min(n, v.shape[1])
    if v.shape[1] > n:
        j = np.argpartition(-df.values, n, 1)[:, :n].ravel()
        i = np.arange(v.shape[0]).repeat(n)
        v[i, j] = True
        return df.where(v, 0)
    else:
        return df

df.groupby(zinv, 1).apply(mask_n, n=2)
```

---

**Option 2**
Usint `rank`

```
zinv = {v: k for k in zones for v in zones[k]}

df.mask(df.groupby(zinv, 1).rank(axis=1, method='first', ascending=False) > 2, 0)
```

Comment: I need to fix something as well.  looking into it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Should be fixed.

Comment: Yes! I settled on rank as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I originally wrote this solution so I'm adding it here as another version.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10)).abs()
N = 2
zones = {"A": [0,1,2], "B": [3,4], "C": [5,6,7,8], "D": [9]}

final = []
for zone_id, cols in zones.iteritems():
    values = {}
    d = df[cols]  # zone A
    for i, row in d.iterrows():
        if len(row) > N:
            row.sort()
            row[row.head(len(row) - N).index] = 0
        values[i] = row
    d = pd.DataFrame(values).T
    final.append(d)

result = pd.concat(final, axis=1)[df.columns]
```

Test answer is the same:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({0: [1.764052, 0., 0.978738, 2.240893, 1.867558, 0.977278, 0.950088, 0., 0., 0.410599],
                             1: [0., 1.454274, 0.761038, 0.121675, 0.443863, 0.333674, 1.494079, 0., 0., 0.854096],
                             2: [2.552990, 0., 0.864436, 0.742165, 2.269755, 1.454366, 0., 0., 1.532779, 1.469359],
                             3: [0., 0.378163, 0.887786, 1.980796, 0.347912, 0., 1.230291, 1.202380, 0., 0.302303],
                             4: [0., 1.420018, 1.706270, 1.950775, 0.509652, 0., 1.252795, 0., 1.613898, 0.212740],
                             5: [0.895467, 0., 0.510805, 1.180632, 0.028182, 0.428332, 0., 0., 0.634322, 0.362741],
                             6: [0.672460, 0., 0.813146, 1.726283, 0.177426, 0., 1.630198, 0., 0.907298, 0.051945],
                             7: [0.729091, 0., 1.139401, 1.234826, 0.402342, 0.684810, 0.870797, 0., 0., 0.056165],
                             8: [1.165150, 0.900826, 0., 1.536244, 1.488252, 1.895889, 1.178780, 0., 0., 1.054452],
                             9: [0.403177, 1.222445, 0., 0.976639, 0.356366, 0.706573, 0., 1.785870, 0., 0.401989],
                             }).T

assert (expected - result).abs().sum().sum() < 0.001
```